# Why can't I clear my input stream?

Tags: c++, stream

```
void Friend::input(std::istream& ins) {
    std::cout << "Please enter a name: ";
    getline(ins, name);
    ins >> std::ws;
    std::cout << "\n\n" << "Please Enter a Birth date in MM/DD/YYYY format: ";
    ins >> bday;
    std::cout<<"\n\n";
}
```

This is the code I am using to enter a name and birthday into a class called Friend. After the getline (to receive both first and last name with a space into one string) My program prints out "Please Enter Birth Date: " and then aborts because the Date class received a value that wasn't a valid date.

I believed that maybe the trailing new line from getline() was stuck in the stream and being inputted to the int for the bday variable which is an instance of a Date class I have been using, but after using:

```
cin >> ws;
```

Nothing changed and my program still aborts due to an invalid value being inserted into the dbay variable. So am I not clearing the stream, or is something else the issue?

edit: Here is the relevant code from Date

```
// input operator, overloaded as a friend
istream& operator >>(istream& ins, Date& d) {
    bool flag = false;
    string junk;

    ins>>d.month;
    // if an invalid month is detected throw a bad_month
    if(d.month < 1 || d.month > 12) {
        getline(ins,junk); // eat the rest of the line
        throw (bad_month(d.month));
    }
    // if the read has failed because of eof exit funtion
    if(ins.eof()) return ins;

    if(ins.peek() == '/') ins.ignore();
    ins>>d.day;

    // if an invalid day is detected throw a bad_day
    if(d.day < 1  || d.day > d.daysallowed[d.month]){
        getline(ins,junk); // eat the rest of the line
        throw (bad_day(d.month, d.day));
    }

    if(ins.eof()) return ins;
    if(ins.peek() == '/') ins.ignore();

    ins>>d.year;

    return ins;
}
```

any values being checked against are simply arrays of acceptable values.

Comment: what does Date look like?

Comment: You need to post the `operator>>()` function that reads a `Date`.

Comment: 1. Your example is far from [ideal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I spent 20 minutes creating a mock-up of parts of your program you could just copy and paste. 2. The resulting code seams to work fine when compiled in [g++](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/3Ru3iWcGCw8ZquAt) and [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GOhwOvEI3YaOPbsw). Sorry if I'm wrong, but I suspect you didn't verify that the problem is in the code you posted.

Comment: If you want to get help, [create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please read the whole article, it's quite small). So far I have 3 guesses: 1. you messed up the initialization of `daysallowed`, 2. some part of your program messed up `daysallowed` by out-of-bounds writing, 3. your input data is formatted incorrectly.